# Want to access only those column names which have mean > 0.0 from df.describe()'s output

Tags: python, pandas

How do I select those columns which have mean>0.0.

This is what I did. Here 'data' is the dataframe of the csv file.

`ds = data.describe()`

`r = ds.loc[ ['mean'] , : ]`

Now this gives one row with mean and all the columns. I have around hundreds columns and just want those having mean > 0.0. I am trying to parse small sub-sets of data as the original one is way too big to be processed at one go.

And how to stretch this to multiple conditions... suppose with mean I want to test standard deviation as well?

I basically was exploring an efficient way of doing as the dataset is pretty huge and the kernel of Jupyter notebook dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with filter by means per columns, here `:` means all rows and for columns we use the condition:

```
df = data.loc[:, data.mean() > 0]
```

Initially here was the error:

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match)

It means there were some columns which were strings, so were excluded, thus not the same values of columns of `df` and index of `ds.loc['mean']`, which raised error. Solution is to add all the columns which were excluded.

```
ds = data.describe()
df = data.loc[:, ds.loc['mean'].reindex(data.columns, fill_value=0) > 0]
```

**Sample**:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})
print (data)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

#removed A,F non numeric columns
ds = data.describe()
print (ds)
              B         C         D         E
count  6.000000  6.000000  6.000000  6.000000
mean   4.500000  5.500000  2.833333  4.833333
std    0.547723  2.880972  2.714160  2.483277
min    4.000000  2.000000  0.000000  2.000000
25%    4.000000  3.250000  1.000000  3.250000
50%    4.500000  5.500000  2.000000  4.500000
75%    5.000000  7.750000  4.500000  5.750000
max    5.000000  9.000000  7.000000  9.000000
```

---

```
df = data.loc[:, ds.loc['mean'].reindex(data.columns, fill_value=0) > 0]
print (df)
   B  C  D  E
0  4  7  1  5
1  5  8  3  3
2  4  9  5  6
3  5  4  7  9
4  5  2  1  2
5  4  3  0  4
```

**Details**:

```
#added columns and filled by 0, so in condition removed
print (ds.loc['mean'].reindex(data.columns, fill_value=0))
A    0.000000
B    4.500000
C    5.500000
D    2.833333
E    4.833333
F    0.000000
Name: mean, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the first one results in dead kernel(as data set is pretty big despite being a subset of the original one) and second one results in this: `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match)`. Also: is there an efficient approach for doing the same?